# Java code doesn't work without a println

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
while(monster.curHp > 0)
{
    System.out.println("");
    if(battle.pressedButton)
    {
        text = Player.name + ": " + Player.curHitPoints + "     " + monster.name + ": " + monster.curHp;
        battle = new GUIForBattle(text,Player,monster);
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that if I have that println line in the while loop the code will work normally and when the button is pressed we will update text to have the current status and we will redraw the GUI using the GUIForBattle class, however if I don't have that println it wont redraw. Any advice? Thank you!

Here is the GUIForBattle for more context

```
public class GUIForBattle extends JFrame {
boolean pressedButton = false;
public GUIForBattle(String words, player PlayerOne, Monster monster)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(); //frame that holds everything
    JPanel Panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,5)); //panel where things get added
    JLabel text = new JLabel(words); // text label
    JButton attack = new JButton("Attack"); //makes a button used to attack
    //adding what pressing the attack button would do 
    attack.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    int attackAmount = PlayerOne.weaponEquipped.att;
                    monster.curHp = monster.curHp - attackAmount;
                    pressedButton = true;
                }
            }
            );
    JButton Item = new JButton("Item"); // makes a button used to use items
    Item.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    //we need to make a item interface
                }
            });
    Panel.add(text); //adds the text to the panel
    Panel.add(attack);
    Panel.add(Item);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(800, 800); //setting size of frame
    frame.add(Panel); //adding the panel to frame
    frame.setVisible(true); //making the frame visible
}
```

}

Comment: This seems highly unlikely and without more context, is impossible to answer

Comment: `System.out.println("");` is probably adding an artificial delay into your loop. Lots of questions get raised by the code - is it running in a separate thread (from the GUI)? Is `battle.pressedButton` `volatile`?

Comment: I'll edit my question to include my GUIForBattle if it'll help

Comment: @Zexdur how did you decided to test it with `System.out.println` when it was not working? Can you remove and just create a variable like `int i = 10;` and check if it behaves differently?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are doing here, but building the GUI inside a loop does not seem to be the right thing to do.

Comment: @MadProgrammer is probably right, try replacing it with something like Thread.sleep(100) and see if it works

Comment: @Zexdur  do you need while loop? you are just printing `monster.curHp` data and really not looping through it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer it's not a delay, it's that OP's `System.out.println` happens to be synchronized which introduces a happens-before into the code, meaning the cached value of `monster.curHp` is invalidated.

Comment: @AndyTurner Fine, but I also find that `System.out.println` introduces a "delay" into code - for the same reason

Comment: @MadProgrammer [*post hoc ergo propter hoc*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_ergo_propter_hoc). The delay it introduces is not relevant.

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions; variable names start with lowercase and class names with uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is inherently multi-threaded; one thread is running through that little `while` loop; the other is the swing application thread that will be handling your swing event handlers.

If you use shared variables like this (both threads access `pressedButton`) you need to make sure that variable is synchronized between threads.  There are several ways of handling this, but an easy way for this particular problem would be to make the variable volatile.

If the variable is not synchronized in any way, there is no guarantee by the JVM as to when one thread will 'see' the changes made to it by the other.  And typically, if you keep one thread occupied like you're doing here (this while loop is called a busy wait) it will never take the time to synchronize, and you'll never see the updates.

The println is an IO operation, meaning at some point your thread will be waiting for IO to complete.  Most likely this causes the JVM to synchronize the variables, which is why you notice this difference.

In any case, relying on this without thinking about synchronization can be considered a bug.

Java threads and memory handling are a complex subject, and not something I would advise for beginners to jump in to; it could be overwhelming.  Just try to avoid sharing memory between threads for now.  For the moment, just run your logic in your swing application code (it's not ideal, but for some beginner code it's probably a good starting point).

When you feel ready for it, read up on [the memory model and what it implies for multi-threading](https://www.developer.com/java/data/understanding-the-java-thread-model.html).